# Sent to wrong bitcoin address

Tags: transactions

Need help I sent my bitcoin cash at the atm to the wrong bitcoin HOW can I use this address to send to the address I want it the money on !!! NEED HELP NOW

Comment: If transaction was confirmed, you lost your funds. I'am sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, it is not possible to revert transactions once they are made because it would allow people to scam others by taking back the money they have paid when they bought something. Your money is lost.

Comment: So I can’t send the money to the address I have to another address????

Comment: You can only send coins that belong to your own addresses. If you have sent the coins to an address that you don't own, the money are out of your control.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what others have posted, your money is not *necessarily* lost forever.

From the sounds of things, you've sent BCH to a Bitcoin (BTC) address, using a bitcoin ATM.

You'll need to contact the operators of the ATM, to ask them to have your funds returned. This is the only way your BCH will be returned. As others have said, there is no way to reverse a confirmed transaction. The coins are now solely controlled by the ATM operator.

Comment: If BCH was sent to a BTC segwit address, you cannot recover it yourself, and must ask a miner for help. [BTC.com](https://bch.btc.com/docs/help/bch_segwit_recovery) offers such a service

Comment: If OP used USD (say) to purchase BCH at an ATM and entered the receiving address of their BTC wallet, couldn't they just import the private key from their BTC wallet into their BCH wallet? (or equivalent process for a multicurrency wallet)